# Chrome, missing table cell

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, html-table, cell

After last Chrome update (45.0.2454.85 m) my web page tables are break. Cells in some rows are missing.

[image: Missing cells]

After some investigation I found that it is probably due to my 'inline' JavaScript code which is part of loop which is printing the cells into row:

```
for ($day = 1; $day <= $n; $day++) { 

  ?>
    <script>
      $(document).ready( function() {     
        some_func($("#tdId<?php echo($day); ?>"));
      });
    </script>
  <?php

  echo(
    "<td>".
    "</td>"
  );

}
```

I found out that problem is with tags `?>\n<script> and </script>\n<?php`. If I will remove the new line. My table looks fine again:

```
for ($day = 1; $day <= $n; $day++) { 

  ?><script>
      $(document).ready( function() {     
        some_func($("#tdId<?php echo($day); ?>"));
      });
  </script><?php

  echo(
    "<td>".
    "</td>"
  );

}
```

And result:
[image: no missing cells]

Is it a Chrome bug? Or it is not alowed to print even new line when table is generating.

Edit:
It can even happen in case:

```
  echo("
    <td>".
    "</td>"
  );
```